# How can I import a huge excel spreadsheet to a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I have many huge excel spread sheets (like 1000 files each having 65000 rows) and need to import into mysql.
Should I use JAVA and use excel libraries?
Should I do it in PHP?
Can you give me sample code to just import a simple excel file into mysql table?

Thanks,

Amir

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby on Rails you can do:

```
require 'csv'    

csv_text = File.read('...')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  YourModel.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
end
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, but I never used Ruby, maybe one day I will give it a shot. For time being, I need it to be done in couple of days.